Can't use flowbite Button into vitest+jsdom?
I'm trying to build basic component testing via vitest and jsdom, so I created vitest.config.js containing:
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import { svelte } from '@sveltejs/vite-plugin-svelte';
import { resolve, dirname } from 'node:path'
import { fileURLToPath } from 'node:url'

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [svelte()],
  test: {
    globals: true,
    environment: 'jsdom',
    alias: [
      {
        find: /\$lib/,
        replacement: resolve(fileURLToPath(dirname(import.meta.url)), '/src/lib'),
      }
    ]
  }
});

and then I test this simple component:
<script lang="ts">
  import { Button } from 'flowbite-svelte';
</script>
<div>
  <Button>
    Foo
  </Button>
</div>

via:
import { describe, it, expect, test } from 'vitest'
import '@testing-library/jest-dom';
import { render } from '@testing-library/svelte/svelte5';

import Home from './Test.svelte';

describe('Basic home rendering', () => {
  it('renders the home with a proper title', () => {
    const result = render(Home);
    
    const headerText = result.getByText('Foo');

    expect(headerText).toBeInTheDocument();
  });
});

sadly I get an error:
Failed test 1:

FAIL  src/routes/home.test.js > Basic home rendering > renders the home with a proper title
Svelte error: lifecycle_outside_component
`getContext(...)` can only be used during component initialisation
 ❯ Module.lifecycle_outside_component node_modules/svelte/src/internal/shared/errors.js:13:17
     12|   const error = new Error(`${"lifecycle_…
     13| 
     14|   error.name = 'Svelte error';
       |                ^
     15|   throw error;
     16|  } else {
 ❯ get_or_init_context_map node_modules/svelte/src/internal/server/context.js:58:25
 ❯ Module.getContext node_modules/svelte/src/internal/server/context.js:18:22
 ❯ Button node_modules/flowbite-svelte/dist/buttons/Button.svelte:36:38
 ❯ Object.fn node_modules/svelte/src/internal/client/dev/hmr.js:37:39
 ❯ execute_reaction_fn node_modules/svelte/src/internal/client/runtime.js:289:20
 ❯ Module.execute_effect node_modules/svelte/src/internal/client/runtime.js:456:18
 ❯ create_effect node_modules/svelte/src/internal/client/reactivity/effects.js:78:26
 ❯ Module.branch node_modules/svelte/src/internal/client/reactivity/effects.js:224:9
 ❯ Object.fn node_modules/svelte/src/internal/client/dev/hmr.js:32:35

If I replace Button with button, the test works fine. Any idea what I'm missing?
